# Android - first run preference initialization

Tags: java, android

I have next situation:
After installing application it has to init settings from server. And while itis not has right preferences it has to wait. I have several receivers and service - I dont want to check for initialization in every action in these components - I think there have to be better solution. Can somebody help me with it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a static class that holds all of the initialization data and it can also hold a boolean for if the values are initialized.

You could also have a class that extends Application and do the initialization in that, so that way you can guarantee that it happens before anything else needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which extends `Application`. Initialize your application inside `onCreate()` method, you can fill some fields of your class.

Then, from any receivers, services or activities, you can retrieve your application class with 
:

```
/* OnCreate method of MyApplication is executed at startup */
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) getApplication();
...
/* you can add any method to retrieve an initialized field */
myApp.getField()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also explore the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) object. It provides the features you seek. You could have key-value pairs that you populate from your server call and in your code you just check if the preference value is what you expect.